# How to tell a form that another form Closes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have "form1" that calls "GameForm". It sends stuff to is like such:

```
            var tmp = new Pjeu(P1, P2);
            tmp.Show();
```

Both "P" are a class. In the "GameForm", it eventually finds a winner and closes itself like such:

```
                MessageBox.Show("Victory " + label3.Text, "Game Finished", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                this.Close();
```

How can i make the "Form1" know that it has closed? I need to do the Game twice to find 2 winner so i need my first form to do the game twice and wait for it to be closed to make another one. I found some answers but none that worked in my context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your GameForm you can create a custom event and rise it before form is  closed. And in your Form1 just subscribe for this event.

In GameForm:

```
public delegate void Winner();
public event Winner OnWinnerFound;
...
OnWinnerFound(); // Just call your event
MessageBox.Show("Victory " + label3.Text, "Game Finished", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            this.Close();
```

In your Form1:

```
var tmp = new Pjeu(P1, P2);
tmp.OnWinnerFound+=WinnerFound;
tmp.Show();
...
private void WinnerFound()
{
  //Your code here
}
```

I don't remember, maybe there is a built in event, which occurs when form is closed or form is closing.

Answer (score 0):

When you create `GameForm` add the `FormClosing` Event handler.

```
GameForm MyForm = new GameForm();
MyForm.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(GameForm_Closing);
MyForm.Show();
```

Make sure you can access the variable within `GameForm` that signifies who won using get-set

```
public string Winner {get; set;} //just an example
```

Then create the handler so you can access that value before the form closes completley.

```
private void GameForm_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = (GameForm)sender;
    myForm1WinnerVariable = obj.Winner;
    //or any other code you want to do as the form closes (eg, increment a variable)
}
```